# Chrome download error "Failed - System busy" when downloading into a Dropbox folder

Tags: windows, google-chrome, dropbox

When downloading a file into a Dropbox folder using Google Chrome on Windows, I often get the download error "Failed - System busy". How can I prevent it? Such issues do not appear when downloading into a non-Dropbox folder.

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

[image]

---

The [suggestions in the Google Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2898334?hl=en) did not help:

> Cancel the download and try again.

I would prefer to avoid that.

> Instead of clicking on the file to download, right click on the link and select Save link as.

I have tried, it didn't help.

> Check that you're downloading the files to a place on your computer you have access to, like your Desktop or Documents folder. You can change download locations.

I should be able to access a Dropbox folder.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2898334?hl=en

Comment: @Moab Thanks. 1) "Cancel the download and try again." -> I would prefer to avoid that. 2) "Instead of clicking on the file to download, right click on the link and select Save link as." I have tried, it didn't help. 3) "Check that you're downloading the files to a place on your computer you have access to, like your Desktop or Documents folder. You can change download locations." I should be able to access a Dropbox folder.

Comment: You say "I should be able to access a Dropbox folder", don't assume...permissions can be changed without your knowledge. Try changing the download location to your Documents folder, if it downloads to there correctly then obviously for some odd reason you do not have enough access to the Dropbox folder.

Comment: @YisroelTech Thanks, such issues do not appear when downloading into a non-Dropbox folder indeed. Why would dropbox folder be sometime accessible, and sometime not (freezing while syncing?), and most importantly is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, I have not answered the question because I'm not sure about the correct solution. But just to speculate, could be that on the moment the Dropbox sync program actually syncs he locks the folder from other process.

Comment: @YisroelTech I'd guess so too, but I'm surprised how long locks are. (fwiw my Internet connection is good)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, well uploading everything and syncing isn't a one two three task, it could take a while. If I'd be you I would check on the Dropbox folder permissions if SYSTEM and Administrators and you user have the Full Control permission.